# Does this sentence make sense? (on the beach is the best place)

Tags: grammar

"On the beach is the best place to play football."
Can the "on the beach" be the subject like in this sentence?

Also, can preposition phrase(like in this sentence)follow the preposition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, preposition phrases can be Subjects in sentences.  However, we need to be careful because they usually only ever occur with the verb *BE* (used in it's specifying sense).

- On the beach **is** the best place to play football.
- On the beach seems to **be** the best place to play football.
- On the beach appears to **be** the best place to play football.

Here are some more examples:

- After Christmas would be the best time for the conference.
- Out of time is what we are.
- Under the stars is the best place for a picnic.

Comment: Is it wrong to say *the beach is the best place to play football on ?*

Comment: @MAKZ Sorry, I didn't read that very carefully. We'd normally drop the *on* there: "The beach is the best place to play football". It sounds odd to use *on* with *place*. We could say something like "*The beach is the best surface to play football on*", though.